# Problema com query usando DB where/orWhere Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde amigos, estou tendo problemas com uma consulta usando DB no laravel,

coloquei uma clausula where e outra orWhere e um whereBetween, porém não está passando pelo between, e quando tiro o orWhere funciona, alguém já passou por isso?

Código:

```
$result = DB::table('tb_monitor_laudo_info')
            ->where('usuariox_operador', 'like', $usuariox)
            ->orWhere('id', '=', $usuariox)
            ->whereBetween('data_laudo',[$datainicial, $datafinal])
            ->orderBy('operador')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário vc utilizar um Parameter Grouping do laravel, para que a ORM não se confunda na relação entre os operadores, veja abaixo como deve ficar:

```
$result = DB::table('tb_monitor_laudo_info')
            ->where('usuariox_operador', 'like', $usuariox)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($usuariox) {
               $query->where('usuariox_operador', 'like', $usuariox)
                 ->orWhere('id', '=', $usuariox);
             })
            ->whereBetween('data_laudo',[$datainicial, $datafinal])
            ->orderBy('operador')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Funcionou!! vlw cara